Cannot capture a handshake when sniffing
I cannot find a way to get a Handshake from my own wireless network, which has a WPA2 encryption. Please, note that this is not the first time I do this at all. In fact, I've captured tons of Handshakes, even when I did not have any idea of what I was doing. My goal is to isolate every possible reason of the capturing failure.
I'm running ParrotOS, installed on my hard disk. My network card is a mt7601u, whose chipset is Ralink. I execute the following commands:
airmon-ng start wlan1
ifconfig wlan1 down
airodump-ng -c 3 --bssid <my_router_mac> -w cap mon0

Obviously, my card does support injection. Anyway, I check it by executing
aireplay-ng -9 mon0
Once I've started sniffing, I try to disconnect manually from the network either my laptop connection with wlan0 interface (which is an Atheros integrated card), my Android phone or a Windows computer.
However, airodump does not show the Handshake found notification at all, even I've been sniffing during more than an hour.
Do you know any reason why it is not working?
